# How can I mirror the output of my iMac's terminal to a physical terminal using serial?

Tags: terminal, macintosh, output

I would like to mirror my iMac's termina onto my Lear Siegler ADM 5 terminal and control it from there. I have a usb to to DB25 cable attached to the extension port on the terminal, but just not sure what settings I have to create to get it working. I don't see anything showing up on the Lear Siegler screen when I run a terminal program on my mac.

Anyone know what settings I need to get it working?

Also, is it then possible to have the Lear Siegler terminal be able to switch between terminal windows from my mac?

Thanks!

Comment: `getty(8)` could provide a terminal to login to, though sharing that with what runs in terminal windows would require something like `tmux` and may not work with a physical terminal so old.